# Xcode: Mac freezes while compiling

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, swift-playground, xcode10

I recently downloaded the Beta version of Xcode 10. I opened an existing project and wanted to start it on a Simulator. But as soon as the Simulator started, may whole mac just froze. I could not do anything. The only thing that worked was moving the mouse.

After rebooting my Mac I thought the freezing was a beta bug in the Xcode 10 Release. So I went back to Xcode 9.4. But when I was using a small playground file, it happened again, while compiling the playground file. After another reboot I tried to recreate the issue with an existing Xcode project I had (the same I used for Xcode 10) but this time the simulator worked without any problems.

I am using:

- MacBook Pro 2010
- 2.2 Ghz Intel Core2Duo Processor
- 16 Gb RAM
- SSD Storage

Is my Mac just too old to work properly with Xcode or does anyone of you knows if this is an issue I can resolve?

Comment: Maybe, but I´m pretty sure I did not use this line in my projects, so I thik it might be something else.

Comment: Same problem with me, occurs with NSOpenPanel and also whenever I press CMD Q, or close a tab in my application. Really annoying... I also submitted a bug report

Comment: I'm having the same problems (MBP 2010 2.4 Ghz 4GB SSD). Regarding my simulators, only iphone 8 plus is causing freezes. Deleting and reinstalling that simulator did not help. Playgrounds is more serious with my entire computer freezing whether Xcode 9.4.1 or Xcode 10. Things were fine before Xcode 10. I only run one Xcode version at a time. This is not a Mojave problem as 2010's highest upgrade is High Sierra. Please post if you find an answer

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this (total system freeze, no pointer movement, nothing) with a single project on 10.14.0GM and Xcode 10, 10A255. I'd gone through and manually deleted the DerivedData folder, everything from the UserData folder except my theme, and DocumentationCache. No luck.

I then did a "Show Package Contents" on the project's `.xcodeproj` file and deleted everything but `project.pbxproj` and attempted opening again. **Success.**

I wasn't concerned with losing the auto-generated schemes on this very simple project structure; be aware that you may lose custom schemes and potentially other customizations related to project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same problem using Xcode 10.0 on a Mac mini (Late 2012) with 16 MB RAM and 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7.

I was using one simulator (an iPhone Xs Max) just fine for a couple of days, but when I changed to an iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 12), my whole computer froze with only the mouse pointer working.  Switching back to the Xs Max simulator did not make the problem go away.  Since I'm not using Playgrounds, switching to running on a real device instead of the simulator "fixed" the issue for me.  Its not a real solution, but it keeps me from grinding to a halt until new versions of Xcode and Simulators come out.